# How to change the decimal places in the vector?

Tags: r, decimal

I'm having trouble with decimals. I have a vector of numbers, for example:

```
x <- c(400000, 500000, 100000, 97500)
```

I would like to turn them like this:

```
x <- c(4000.00, 5000.00, 1000.00, 975.00)
```

I've tried commands like `round`, `format` and `options`, but all they do is to add more zeros to these numbers. How to change the decimal places in the vector?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: divide it by 100

Comment: Try this `format(x/100, nsmall = 2)`. Credit to @dww

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you guys!

Comment: One thing to note -- unlike in Excel, numeric data in R doesn't have inherent formatting. It's only when you convert it to a character form (e.g. by using `format` or `formatC` that formatting is applied, but it also stops being numeric data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the function `formatC()`

```
formatC(as.numeric(x/100), format = 'f', flag='0', digits = 2)
```